# Dynamically created tabs not showing after creation in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm just using a button now to try and get it to work. It is supposed to make another selection in the dropdown box which it does, then show the content page. However it isn't changing the display to the page that was created and instead I have to manually click the new selection in the dropdown.

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="srTabs">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#search">Search</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#upload">Upload</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#notes">Notes</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" id="subDropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Submissions <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="submissionContainer">
      <li><a href="#grid" data-toggle="tab">Grid</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#history">History</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content" id="srContent">
  <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <div id="navigationBar" class="text-center">
      <button onclick="makeSub(150)">Test</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="search" class="tab-pane fade"></div>

  <div id="upload" class="tab-pane fade"></div>

  <div id="notes" class="tab-pane fade"></div>

  <div id="grid" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h1 align="center">Submissions</h1>
  </div>

  <div id="history" class="tab-pane fade">
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
function makeSub(id) {
    $('<li><a href="#sub'+id+'" data-toggle="tab">'+id+'</a></li>').appendTo('#submissionContainer');
    $('<div id="sub'+id+'" class="tab-pane fade"></div>').appendTo('#srContent');
    $('#sub'+id).load('/webapp/submissions/' + id);
    $('#sub'+id).tab('show');   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either have to bind click event to the button [like in this fiddle I made](http://jsfiddle.net/eLdws429/2/), or move your `makeSub` function outside of the `$.ready` function where button's `onclick` event can find the function.

```
$.ready(function(){
//everything else
});

function makeSub(id) {
$('<li><a href="#sub'+id+'" data-toggle="tab">'+id+'</a></li>').appendTo('#submissionContainer');
$('<div id="sub'+id+'" class="tab-pane fade"></div>').appendTo('#srContent');
$('#sub'+id).load('/webapp/submissions/' + id);
$('#sub'+id).tab('show');   
}
```

Comment: I tried both of the methods and neither one I can get to work. It will create the tab but it will now switch over to show it automatically. I still have to go to the dropdown and select it.

Comment: Checkout the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eLdws429/3/). Does what you expect. I added an id on the newly created dropdown item, and trigger a click on it rather than doing `.tab('show')` on the tab body.